# c# From a Formless Form2 to from1 window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

im trying to get the any type of TEXT from form2 to from 1
i used

```
button_click()
{
form1 text1 = new form1();
text1.textbox.text = "lol";
}
```

but it wont update from1 with it. it just sends nulls
then i found this class

[Set value into a property in Class1 from Form1 then get value of that property in Class1 to Form2 using C# Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551379/set-value-into-a-property-in-class1-from-form1-then-get-value-of-that-property-i)

it gets what i want problem is i want it to update textbox asap instead of pressing button on both forms to make it update
if i could just get it to update from form2 it would be awsome.

i even tried the

```
public form1(string text)
{
  textBox.Text = text;
}
```

form2

```
form1 textbox = new form1(textbox.text);
```

http://bildr.no/view/1232007

Comment: Add `text1.Show()` to your first snippet to see a result.  Understanding the difference between types and object is very core to .NET programming.  Find a book or school to help yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Application.OpenForms` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) to get the reference to the other form:

```
Form1 form1 = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;
if(form1 != null)
{
    form1.SetTextBoxText("lol");
}
```

You need to provide a public method `SetTextBoxText` in `Form1` to change the  text  in the TextBox:

```
public void SetTextBoxText(String text)
{
    textBox.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: it didn work i did as u said it just wont find it in the . `Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'SetTextBoxText' and no extension method 'SetTextBoxText' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
`

Comment: @coldasice: You have to cast the form to `Form1` in this way:  `((Form1)form1).SetTextBoxText("blah");` Edited my answer accordingly.